# 夢は〜を持つことです　VS　夢は〜を持ちたいです

Tags: grammar

This sentence is from my textbook:

> 私の将来の夢は自分の店を［持つことです／*持ちたいです］。

In other words, it says that 持ちたいです is incorrect in this case.

But since the topic is 私の将来の夢、持ちたい seems like a perfectly suitable response. Why isn't it?

Is the second sentence maybe saying, "My dream is *to want* to open my own store"?

Comment: 私の将来の夢は自分の店を持ちたいです literally means "My dream wants to have its own store." as if your dream had its own will.

Comment: @naruto What I don't get is, why is 夢 assumed to be the subject? It's marked by は, not が. Had the sentence been: 私の将来の夢が自分の店を持ちたいです、then I would see what you're saying. But as I mentioned to macraf in another comment, there are sentences like 秋は空がきれいです、or 僕はウナギだ where the は-marked word is not the subject, but the topic.

Comment: @naruto Would 私の将来の夢は自分の店を持ちたいです be a correct response to the question, 将来の夢は何をしてほしいですか?

Comment: @Nahcin Good, so you already know about うなぎ文. Indeed, sentences like 私の将来の夢は自分の店を持ちたいです is occasionally heard in reality, as macraf pointed out, but that's not something beginners should learn.   I think your textbook is just dealing with basic and standard grammar :) And 私の夢が自分の店を持ちたい is out of the question, yes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1 : 私の将来の夢は**自分の店を持つこと**です。(correct)
>   2 : 私の将来の夢は**自分の店を持ちたい**です。(incorrect)
>   3 : 私の将来の夢は**自分の店を持ちたいということ**です。(correct)

The sentence structure of 1 is "A is B" where A and B are nouns or noun clauses.
As you know A is 私の将来の夢 and B is 自分の店を持つこと in 1, but 自分の店を持ちたい in 2 is not a noun.
To change 自分の店を持ちたい into a noun clause you should add "ということ" to it as in 3.

## EDIT

Thanks to Yuuichi Tam's comment, I'll add useful information to my answer.

If you do not stick to "A is B" which is the sentence structure of 1 and you want to use the expression in the second half of 2 as it is, you'll get a grammatically correct sentence like 4.

> 4 : 私は将来、**自分の店を持ちたい**。 or 私は将来、**自分の店を持ちたい**です。

4 sounds much more natural to the native Japanese than 3.

If you want to use 夢 by all means in 4, it'll become like 5.

> 5 : 私は将来の夢として**自分の店を持ちたい**。 or 私は将来の夢として**自分の店を持ちたい**です。

Comment: 私の将来の夢は自分の店を持ちたいということです is a bit unnatural, isn't it? I think 私は将来、自分の店を持ちたい or 私の将来の夢は自分の店を持つことです are natural.

Comment: I believe OP's interpretation/confusion comes from visualising someone answering this particular question. I at least can imagine a situation in which there is a pause for thinking after は and the subsequent phrase does not necessarily have to match the build up. In a textbook exercise (and without punctuation) it is wrong, no doubt, but in a dialogue? It doesn't strike as blatantly wrong or incomprehensible.

Comment: @macraf Admittedly I sometimes hear 「明日の予定は、動物園に行きましょう」. 「問題は、そのボタンを押しても反応しません」 or such, even from some native speakers. They're comprehensible but are far from proper.

Comment: @Yuuichi Tam: 文章の自然さに関しては、あなたの言うとおりです。しかし、それは質問者が「このような質問をしなくなった」あとのテーマだと思いました。まずは、どういう表現が自然であるか以前に、文法的になぜおかしいのか、そして、文法的なおかしさからどうすれば脱出できるのかを伝えるべく回答したつもりです。ともかくありがとうございます。

Comment: @Yuuichi Tam: あなたのコメントを生かすべくEDITしました。

Comment: @macraf That's right, my confusion is from my knowledge that は doesn't necessarily mark the subject of the sentence, it marks the topic of discussion. In a sentence like: 秋は空がきれいです、秋 is not the subject, it's the time topic. "The sky is clear in autumn."

So by analogy, I'm thinking of this sentence as 私の夢は自分の〜を持ちたい as something like "As for my dream, [I] want to have [my own] 〜."  Based on context I don't see how someone could mistake 夢 as the subject here, when the ending is 持ちたい.

Answer (score 2):

You are already answering your own question. The translation of the incorrect answer is: "My dream is to want to open a store"... it simply doesn't make sense in any language.

It is basically a mix of the following two sentences, that individually mean similar things:

> 私{わたし}の将来{しょうらい}の夢{ゆめ}は自分{じぶん}の店{みせ}を持{も}つことです。 = My dream is to have my own store
>
> 私は自分の店を持ちたいです。 = I want to have my own store

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68517/discussion-on-answer-by-bjorn-vs).